# How can I filter my home network?

Tags: mac-address, traffic-filtering, bandwidth

I live in an apartment with one roomate. They have a monopoly, as the complex actually has it's own special ISP they offer...and they restrict other, better providers like Verizon, Charter, and so on. We have a relatively, but strictly enforced, bandwidth cap of 200 gb per month. After 200 gb, we receive a letter, and our speeds are dramatically reduced.

For the past 3 - 4 months, we've reached the cap every month, and due to work and school, I'm only there a few hours a day. I talked about it with my roomate, and he's been downloading torrent files as big as 70 gb, and streaming lengthy podcasts that are FLAC file type.

I've asked him to stop, as these things are causing us to reach our cap fairly quickly...and it's frustrating. He hasn't stopped. Is there anyway I can restrict his access on the home network? The modem is connected to a wireless router that I bought two years ago, I know the password and can log in any time to change the settings. The router page has a mac address filtering tab, but it doesn't work very well and I can't quite figure out how to kick him off the network. How would I go about this?

Comment: What model router do you have?  Does it support QOS or parental filters?  If not, is your router supported by Tomato or DD-WRT?

Comment: Do you use the same computer? or both have individual?

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address filtering should be working, unless he's spoofing his address, is torrenting from a device you're not blocking (cell phone, tablet), or is using a NIC that you're not accounting for. We have two routers in our home, and on both you have the option to either:

- Block specific MAC addresses from connecting, or
- Permit *only* the MAC addresses you specify to connect.

If your router allows the latter feature, have you given it a try?